ElasticSearch Geo Shape Query doesn't return items within the polygon that do exist
I have the following ElasticSearch (v8.15.*) query which isn't returning items I know exist in the index; a small tweak to the values in the polygon does then return the expected items.
GET test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "geo_shape": {
      "geopoint": {
        "shape": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [
                -194,
                -90
              ],
              [
                180,
                -90
              ],
              [
                180,
                90
              ],
              [
                -194,
                90
              ],
              [
                -194,
                -90
              ]
            ]
          ]
        },
        "relation": "intersects"
      }
    }
  }
}

This polygon covers the globe with some overlap, You can see in Elastics map tool that it understands the shape and can see the overlap

Here is a snippet of my data in the index to show that it exists
"hits": [
    {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_id": "XXX",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "geopoint": {
                    "lon": -1.865,
                    "lat": 53.811
                },
            ...,
        }
    },
    ...,
]   

Which is within the range of the geo shape query provided above.
Here is the mapping for the geopoint property in the index that the query is targeting
"geopoint": {
    "type": "geo_point"
}

So here is the polygon shape and direction

I don't understand why this is not finding the result, but if you change the bottom right and top right longitudes to 179 rather than 180 it works as expected and returns the item in the index.
I initially expected it was due to the overlap but the change to the longitudes from 180 to 179 works and doesn't remove the overlap.

I tried changing the orientation value from the default RIGHT to LEFT in the query based on some comments in Elastic documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html#polygon-orientation regarding the size of the longitudes but this made no difference.

Also tried changing the right / left hand rule to draw the rectangle to bottom left, top left, top right, bottom right and back to bottom left rather than the opposite direction given in the example query, also with no change in results



Was able to index the shape with the appropriate mappings and then surface it in the map application in kibana and there I can see that the shape wasn't as expected and the issue is due to the polygon crossing the IDL (anti-meridian problem)
So, looks like I will need to split the rectangle polygon into two to wrap it around to the normal coordinates
